# Jetpack Compose Drag and Drop in LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way how to enable drag and drop in LazyVerticalGrid ?
I have dashboard with couple of "tiles" and need to reposition them by dragging.
I found this library: https://github.com/aclassen/ComposeReorderable , but I can not apply it to Grid layout.
Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-built function in Compose library that enables drag-and-drop but you can copy files from that library you mentioned (https://github.com/aclassen/ComposeReorderable) and use it in your own project. This worked in my case.